# Does time homogeneity imply strong Markov property in a Markovian process

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Does a time homogeneous Markovian process necessarily have strong Markovian property? Does continuity in state space, time, or path make a difference? What are the examples if it does not?

Comment: Which examples of Markov processes not strong Markov do you know?

Comment: @Did: Is it supposed to be a hint? But I do not see how this is relevant. Any time inhomogeneous Markov process does not possess strong Markov property.

Comment: This is an interesting question, because if your claim that any time inhomogeneous Markov process does not possess the strong Markov property is true, then that would be a necessary condition, and hence your question comes down to determining whether or not time homogeneity is both sufficient and necessary, i.e. equivalent, for a Markov process to possess the strong Markov property. If you have heard any developments, I at least would be greatly interested to hear the answer.